How to remove footer from Microsoft Teams Message send with Powerapps Workflow?
Microsoft is retiring the Office 365 connectors from Microsoft Teams, including the webhook one that allows automatic messaging through very simple POST message (see this devblog from microsoft).
I am switching to the given solution of using a PowerApps flow named : Post to a channel when a webhook request is received
Everything is working great but I have a deeply, ugly, and irritating footer that is added to every message (and sometimes, when using action buttons, not at the bottom). It is written "[USERNAME] used a Workflow template to send this card. Get template".
How can I disable the footer in my JSON request. My current body is :
{
        "type": "message",
        "attachments": [ {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
             "contentUrl":null,
             "content":{
                "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type":"AdaptiveCard",
                "version":"1.2",
                "msteams": {
                    "width": "Full",
                },
                "body":[
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "medium",
                        "weight": "bolder",
                        "text": "Header Text",
                        "style": "heading",
                        "wrap": false
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "Simple text"
                        "wrap": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


An alternative approach could be using adaptive cards. Those are fully customisable.

Creating a copy of your workflow seems to do the trick. Found this out through this post. Worked for me.

It did the trick, thanks! I was kind of sure this would not work. This is so weird, it means that the Teams created webhook is embedding some kind of info about showing the footer... Nice hack!

Currently, there is no direct way to remove this footer through the JSON request or the workflow interface. It is automatically added to cards sent using certain templates.

Is there any way to know which templates get this message? Or why?

Do you know if there is any plans to remove the ad footer before October 1st and the closure of the O365 connectors in MS Teams ?

Microsoft has decided to extend the retirement timeline through December 2025 to provide ample time to migrate to another solution such as Power Automate, an app within Microsoft Teams, or Microsoft Graph. Please find latest update here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
